# Named scopes in templates

Tags: freemarker

Is it possible to name some blocks inside ftl and get them on java side? For example something like with incrorrect syntax maybe

```
#emailSubject[
This is email subject]
#emailMessage
[Email multi-
line message!!
Hi all]
```

and java side looks like

```
template.process("template.ftl", resultModelOrSomethingElse);
String emailSubject = resultModelOrSomethingElse.getEmailSubject();
String emailMessag = resultModelOrSomethingElse.getEmailMessage();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out-of-the-box, you can do this:

```
<#assign emailSubject>This is the email subject</#assign>

<#assign emailMessage>
  This is the email message...
</#assign>
```

and then:

```
// Same as template.process, but you will have the Environment:
Environment env = template.createProcessingEnvironment(dataModel, out);
env.process();

// Extract top-level variables:
TemplateModel emailSubject = env.getVariable("emailSubject");
TemplateModel emailMessage = env.getVariable("emailMessage");
```

(If it's something that you will do a lot, you might want to streamline this in the template. Like `<@emailSubject>This is the email subject</@>` is terser and more fool-proof, as it will immediately fail if somebody makes a mistake in the "emailSubject" variable name.)